# How to rectify the python error: "icon object is not callable"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I have a dictionary where there are certain elements and associated keys. I want to create a GUI to display the items. I have used a QMessageBox PyQt widget within a for loop. But when i run the code i am getting a following error:

**Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python34_64bit\dictt.py", line 50, in  main() File "C:\Python34_64bit\dictt.py", line 45, in main GUI=MYGUI() File "C:\Python34_64bit\dictt.py", line 31, in init self.Choice=QtGui.QMessageBox.Question(self,k,val,QtGui.QMes‌​sageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No) TypeError: 'Icon' object is not callable**

Kindly help me how to fix this issue with a modification to my code. Below is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

class MYGUI(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MYGUI,self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("GUI")

        #widgets:

        self.labl=QtGui.QLabel(self)    
        self.labl.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Calibri', 34))


        #Layout:

        Layout =QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        Layout.addWidget(self.labl)
        Layout.addStretch()
        self.setLayout(Layout)

        #Actions:                


        Queries={'Q1':'question 1','Q2':'question2'}

        for k,val in Queries.items():

            self.Choice=QtGui.QMessageBox.Question(self,k,val,QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

            if choice==QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
                self.labl.setText('yes')

            else:
                self.labl.setText('No')

        self.show()


def main():

    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI=MYGUI()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


main()
```

Comment: You should include the full error trace in your question, especially the part that points out in which line the error happens.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34_64bit\dictt.py", line 50, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python34_64bit\dictt.py", line 45, in main
    GUI=MYGUI()
  File "C:\Python34_64bit\dictt.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.Choice=QtGui.QMessageBox.Question(self,k,val,QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
TypeError: 'Icon' object is not callable

Comment: @pavansunder in your question; not as comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is just with lower/upper case.

`QMessageBox.Question` is the icon

`QMessageBox.question(parent, title, text, button0, button1)` is the function

See: https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QMessageBox.html